# Add tools with GIF background (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I already typed codes for some tools(text/button/label), but once i put a gif background they disappeared. the question is .. How to get them into the foreground?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {


    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("tiger", ofType: "gif")
    let gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

    let webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    webViewBG.loadData(gif!, MIMEType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: String(), baseURL: NSURL())
    webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = false;
    self.view.addSubview(webViewBG)
}
```

Comment: What is your concrete problem? At the moment, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: my concrete problem is : I built some UIButton and UIText codes in my "storyboard" then i drag them into the vieController to code them, till this moment everything working well. then i got some codes for GIF background as you can see in the top .. once i code them (the GIF background that i selected,,  became above UIButton and UIText, so i can press them i have to make them in the foreground but they became behind the background .. where i can't press them ... i hope it's clear  ( i can't explain very well .. sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I'd say that when you call addSubview method, the view you are adding is on the foreground.

You have to call one of these methods to manipulate view hierarchy :

```
view.sendSubviewToBack(view: UIView)
view.bringSubviewToFront(view: UIView)
```

What I'd do is to add the subview, then send it to the background with sendSubviewToBack method

**UPDATE** :
Seems that it doesn't work that way. There will be several solutions you could use. Either you keep your web view and your view separated but with the same frame so that your view is just on top of your web view.

Problem is that if your frame changes, you have to change the frames of both views.

Another solution is to add your label inside your web view (didn't test it though but it works with an image view so I assume it may work).

Comment: i'm sorry. could you explain that very clearly please?

Comment: A UILabel or whatever inherits from UIView. But a UIView can contain multiple views which can contain other views and so on. Here, you add your web view inside another UIView. When you do it, your web view goes on top of the view hierarchy of your label. That means that your web view is going on top of the view that contains the text of your label. If you want to have your web view behind the text, you have to send your web view to the background of your label view hierarchy. You can do it by doing `label.sendSubviewToBack(web view)`. I talk about a label for example but works with UIView.